# Network issue - Flask on raspberry pi get stuck on outbound response when accessing from Internet

Tags: networking, flask, raspberry-pi

I have an issue about configuration the Flask on raspberry pi so that it can be accessed the web server from internet. The Flask is configured as 0.0.0.0 already as

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True , host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

I have managed to access the web from LAN like below

```
    P:\Desktop\py>curl 218.191.220.131:8080/restful/demo {
  "result": [
    {
      "humidity": 57.13673400878906,
      "id": 1,
      "temperature": 31.51284408569336,
      "time": "12:45:30"
    }
  ]
}
```

However when i try access it from internet, the response is stuck. I can see from the debug message the request is sent successfully to Flask

```
192.168.1.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 11:23:06] "GET /restful/demo HTTP/1.1" 200 - # accessed from LAN
14.0.229.145 - - [18/Jan/2017 11:23:17] "GET /restful/demo HTTP/1.1" 200 - # accessed from Internet
```

it looks like the response cannot send successfully, stuck at FIN_WAIT1 likely means the response failed to reach to client.

```
pi@pi:~/Desktop/py $ netstat -n | grep 8080
tcp        0    155 192.168.1.116:8080      14.0.229.145:18934      FIN_WAIT1
tcp        0    155 192.168.1.116:8080      14.0.229.145:18935      FIN_WAIT1
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.116:8080      192.168.1.1:52304       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.116:8080      192.168.1.1:52311       TIME_WAIT
```

Any idea please? I've already setup port forwarding/ triggering and even try DMZ mode but still stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. it is due to my synology router treat the package is intrusive and blocked. I have disabled the intrusive prevention mode and it can now access from the internet.